# My Javascript is getting stuck on something

Tags: javascript

So below is the snippet of code that is causing me problems.
There is a bunch of stuff before here that works ok.

```
if (numWOOD_OK) 
    {
    return true;    
    }
else {  
    alert("Number of bags must be a whole number");
    return false;                             
    }   
if (numDISTANCE<=0)                             
    {                       
    alert("Input for distance is invalid");                 
    return false;                       
    }
```

Basically the `if (numWOOD_OK)` is running a a RegExp declared earlier on, and if it returns false it means a decimal has been entered into the input box in question - which we don't want.

The `if (numDISTANCE<=0)` is checking if a particular input box is empty. It is set up the same way as the half-dozen other checks before the `if (numWOOD_OK)`.

The problem is, the `if (numDISTANCE<=0)` will not fire.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: We need more code, can you post a jsfiddle for us? Because whatever the variable numDISTANCE is, is your problem.

Comment: Try posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), the way the question stands right now lacks enough data to be answered properly. Also consider reproducing the SSCCE in a live environment such as http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always return true or false before you reach that if condition, so it will never execute.

You can rewrite to make it work like this:

```
if (!numWOOD_OK)  {
    alert("Number of bags must be a whole number");
    return false;                             
}   
if (numDISTANCE<=0) {                       
    alert("Input for distance is invalid");                 
    return false;                       
}
return true;
```

Comment: Cheers for that mate, did the trick nicely. Now I have to wait five minutes to mark yours as the answer...........(drums fingers on the desk)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever function your inside ends with one of those return statements above it. If you have code like this

```
if(this) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
// this part will never execute
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time the code gets to that if, it will have already returned from the function. Returning short-circuits the logic and stops the function immediately. You might consider using a local variable to store the return value, and return that at the end:

```
var ret;
if (numWOOD_OK) 
    {
    ret = true;
    }
else {  
    alert("Number of bags must be a whole number");
    ret = false;                        
    }   
if (numDISTANCE<=0)                             
    {                       
    alert("Input for distance is invalid");                 
    ret = false;     
    }
return ret;
```